# R: How to extract charts from MS Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: r, excel, vba, charts, extract

I've looked around, but wasn't able to find a way to automatically extract charts from Excel spreadsheets. (My tool of choice is R, but I'd consider alternatives.)

Has anyone done it?

Update: I've got a bunch of spreadsheets I created using Excel 2013, and I'd like to extract all charts as pictures (e.g. PNG). I don't mind using VBA, but I need to be able to run code on *all* spreadsheets at once, as going through them one by one would defeat the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you have Excel available (which version)? Would a VBA solution be fine?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Well, I would use VBA (mind you, I wouldn't produce these charts in Excel). There is an export method for chart objects, so this shouldn't be too difficult. You might want to add the VBA tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all of your charts are embedded in normal worksheets (e.g. Sheet1, Sheet2) and not chart sheets (e.g. Chart1)... Try something like this in VBA:

```vb
Sub exportAllCharts()

Dim folder As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cObj As ChartObject

folder = "C:\"  'Make sure to have the trailing slash
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    For Each cObj In ws.ChartObjects
      filename = wb.Name & " " & ws.Name & " " & cObj.Name & ".png" 'Or whatever your code is to name your file...
      cObj.Chart.Export folder & filename
    Next cObj
  Next ws
Next wb
End Sub
```

I tested it and it works. That should iterate all open workbooks, all worksheets, and export all chart objects.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

I've to open all the spreadsheets, but it's still much less manual work that extracting all charts by hand.

Comment: You're welcome! You can iterate through your folder(s) and open & close files. Look into the Dir() function. Then use application.workbooks.open.